# How can I tell Git to forget about a file completely?

Tags: git

I am using my `master` branch to hold base 'material' files which are used in child branches for various projects. Let's say I work for a company which makes wagons as well as downhill skis. My master branch would contain all the files which are used as parts for those products. Each product is branched from `master` (`wagon` branch, `ski` branch, etc). The parts not needed for each project are then removed using `git rm` (although skis on a wagon *do* sound like fun).

The problem is, whenever I merge my `master` branch (material changes perhaps) into a project branch (**wagon** for instance) `git` thinks I really want the changes to the files which I've `git rm`'d into oblivion, and adds them back for me - *Version master of skis left in tree* as shown code below.

How can I get `git` to *really* and *truly* forget about a file I've told it to forget about and stop tracking?

---

add some parts to `master`, and commit:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/parts
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/parts/.git/
$ echo rubber > wheels
$ echo steel > skis
$ echo vinyl > seat
$ echo wood > sides
$ ls
seat  sides  skis  wheels
$ 
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m 'initial parts'
[master (root-commit) ca7610e] initial parts
 4 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 seat
 create mode 100644 sides
 create mode 100644 skis
 create mode 100644 wheels
```

Create a `wagon` project branch and remove the parts that we do not need on a wagon:

```
$ git checkout -b wagon
Switched to a new branch 'wagon'
$ ls
seat  sides  skis  wheels
$ git rm skis
rm 'skis'
$ git rm seat
rm 'seat'
$ git commit -a -m 'initial wagon design'
[wagon 384b246] initial wagon design
 2 files changed, 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 seat
 delete mode 100644 skis
```

The engineering team has decided to change some materials. Commit those changes in `master` so they are available to all our projects:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
seat  sides  skis  wheels
$ 
$ echo 'titanium' > skis
$ echo 'metal' > sides
$ git commit -a -m 'design requirements call for stronger sides and skis'       
[master a8bf4c4] design requirements call for stronger sides and skis
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

We need *some* of the changes in the `wagon` project so merge `master` to get them but now git is complaining:

```
$ git checkout wagon
Switched to branch 'wagon'
$ git merge master
CONFLICT (modify/delete): skis deleted in HEAD and modified in master. Version master of skis left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the most workable solution I've found is to merge master into the current branch and then use `--porcelain` to print out a list of `Deleted Updated` files and then call `xargs` to remove them:

`git status --porcelain | awk '{if ($1=="DU") print $2}'`

It's not pretty. It would be nice to plug this into a `pre-merge` git hook but that apparently does not exist.

Comment: Thumbs up for comically missing the point. You're misusing `git`, and really need to think about finding a better package for what you're doing.

Comment: May be, but If you have another solution to accomplish this, please post it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be using git not as a source control system but more like a solution manager. Think about it, why would you put files under source control if you want to remove a different part of them whenever you checkout a new branch?

Feature branches are forks on the development path that are intended to be merged with master and bring additional functionality to the entire project.

You can create a repo for each material and then set up a project build to fetch required materials from material repos.